# Multipage Javascript stylesheet changer changes stylesheet in only one subpage, not in all of them

Tags: javascript, cookies, stylesheet

My website has 5 pages. I would like to allow user to change the look and feel by clicking on a hyperlink. I would also like the changed style to be stored in cookies. So when I change the stylesheet from the homepage, the rest 4 pages will be changed as well. The problem is when I change the stylesheet from the fifth page, only the stylesheet on the fifth page had changed, the rest are not changed when I navigated to those pages. Similarly, I changed the stylesheet on the forth 4 page, only this particular page's stylesheet had changed.

Below is the javascript code:

```
var styleNo = parseInt(document.cookie.charAt(6));
var styleFile;
if( isNaN(styleNo) ) // style not selected by user initially, usually not a number at char 6
    styleFile = "/nmc/css/style" + 0 + ".css";
else {
    styleFile = "/nmc/css/style" + styleNo + ".css";
}

document.writeln('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' + styleFile + '">');

function changeStyle( styleNo ){
    var CookieDate = new Date;
    CookieDate.setFullYear(CookieDate.getFullYear( ) +10);
    document.cookie = "style=" + styleNo + "; expires=" + CookieDate.toGMTString() + ";";
    window.location.reload();
}
```

Below is the coding when the hyperlink is clicked

```
<div id="styleSelection">
    <a href="#" onclick="changeStyle(0)">Style 1</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="changeStyle(1)">Style 2</a>
</div>
```

Any tips for solving this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Is your if/else statement to parse and select a style executed on every page load?

Comment: and what does it reurn when it is not working?(use firebug or chrome development tools)

Comment: Does this pattern repeat itself for all of the pages, or just the fourth and fifth?

Comment: @pwdst Repeat itself for all of the pages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible that you're setting the cookie in a subdirectory. If this is the case, that cookie will only effect that subdirectory. The first answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6387250/setting-cookies-on-directories) post explains this phenomenon.